# Commutation spin operators

Tags: operators, angular-momentum, commutator

I am reading about the spin commutation relations and the common ones i find are:

[image]

But how do you find say ${[S_x,S_z]}$ is it the same result as ${[S_z,S_x]}$?

Comment: Do you know what expression a commutation relation represents? The definition should be in the same book you are using to find the spin commutation relations.

Comment: Well doesn't the order of the operators matter thats what i was confused with - as i assumed swapping the terms would change the result. Maybe i should ask on a math forum as it doesn't seem like i'll get the help here.

Comment: $[A,B]\ne [B,A]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the anticommutator of two operators $A$ and $B$ is

$$[A,B] := AB - BA$$

$$\Rightarrow [B,A] = BA - AB = -(AB - BA) = -[A,B]$$

Thus

$$[S_x, S_z] = -[S_z, S_x] = -i \hbar S_y$$

In general

$$[S_i, S_j] = i \hbar \epsilon_{i j k} S_k$$

where $\epsilon_{i j k}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol.